# Is there a Python module to detect month or day in string?

Tags: python, date

Is there a Python module to parse month or day references in a given string?

Comment: That question is hopelessly vague and difficult to answer.  Please provide an example of a "month or day reference".  Is "12" a month reference or a day reference?  How can you tell?

Comment: A good answer below but yes, fuzzy=True

Comment: "A good answer below" isn't an answer to my question.  What is "12"?  Please provide an example of the kinds of "month or day reference" you're talking about and what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could try using `dateutil.parser`, e.g.:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse("There's a date 09-21 in here", fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 21, 0, 0)
```

... with the `fuzzy=True` option.  The documentation is [here](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c).

Answer (score 0):

Are any other characters in the string or just numbers which says the date? If you have a date string and you want to create a date which you can format, try this:

```
import time
```

time.strptime(datestring,"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S") # for example 17.03.2011 10:05:15

You can also create an UNIX timestamp

```
timestamp = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date,"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")))
```

You can use wide range of formats, more info [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Another possibility is to combine this with a regular expression on the string, but Mark's module would be much better for this.